# How to make a custom Echo

Tags: function-construction, debugging, monitoring

I usually check my intermediate variable by `Echo`.Like

```
Table[Echo@x, {x, 10}]
```

[image]

But when the intermediate variable have too much value,the *Font-End* often crash,such as `Table[Echo@x, {x, 10^3}]`.So I want to make a custom `myEcho`,which always show the first `5` results when I run `Table[myEcho@x, {x, 10}]` every time.Like

```
Table[myEcho@x, {x, 10}]
```

[image]

Or we can specify the times that we hope,such as `Table[myEcho[x,3], {x, 10}]` will show the first `3` results

---

As the [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba)'s fix,this is current method.

```
Clear[fun, myEcho]
fun[n_: 5] := 
 Module[{times = 0}, (times++; If[times <= n, Echo, Identity][#]) &]

myEcho = fun[5];
Table[myEcho@x, {x, 10}]
```

But the weakness is obvious still,which mean I should run `myEcho = fun[5];Table[myEcho@x, {x, 10}]` every time.Actually I hope get a same result when I just run `Table[myEcho@x, {x, 10}]`.

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, since 2021, years after this question, there is a resource function that limits the number of outputs from `Echo` named `LimitEcho` : https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/LimitEcho/

Comment: I should mention that I have not yet used it myself so I do not know how well it works.

Comment: @userrandrand Yes, but is very very very slow, you can test `ResourceFunction["LimitEcho"][ImageApply[Echo[#]&,ExampleData[{"TestImage","Lena"}]],5]`

Comment: I checked and yep it seems like the echos are still being produced as there is a button to show all the echos that occurred. That might also lead to problems with memory not sure.  Why not `c = 0; ImageApply[If[c < 5, c++; Echo[#], #] &, 
 ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]]` ? That could be tedious to reset c=0 each time we need it for a new code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

### Update

I figured that I can make the code much faster (close to the speed without any `Echo`) if I can get rid of all the `if`'s and let the pattern matcher(which is pretty fast) do all the heavy work for me.

```
BeginPackage["MyEcho`"];

MaxEchoCount=5;
MyEcho::stop="Max Echo count of `` reached, further `` will be suppressed during evaluation of In[``].";
SetAttributes[MyEcho,HoldAllComplete]

Module[{list={}},
MyEcho[label_,return_,subexpr___]:=
Which[
list[[label]]<MyEcho`MaxEchoCount,list[[label]]++;Echo[return,subexpr],
list[[label]]==MyEcho`MaxEchoCount,Message[MyEcho::stop,MyEcho`MaxEchoCount,Defer[Echo[return,subexpr]],$Line];MyEcho[label,return1_,subexpr1___]:=return1;return];

$Pre=Function[{expr},
Quiet@Cases[DownValues[MyEcho],HoldPattern[MyEcho[label_Integer,e___]]:>Unset[MyEcho[label,e]],Infinity];
list=ConstantArray[0,Length@list];
ReleaseHold[Hold[expr]/. HoldPattern[Echo[subexpr__]]:>With[{c=(AppendTo[list,0];Length@list)},MyEcho[c,subexpr]/;True]],HoldAll];
];

EndPackage[];
```

The key here is that I will add a narrower definition to `MyEcho` once it reached the maximum echo count, so the next time it meets the same function at the same place, it will hit the new function definition and directly return.

One can compare this version to the old version, as well as the version with `QuietEcho` wrapped around the whole expression with the following code:

```
Table[Flatten[{{Table[Echo[x], 2], Echo[10 - x]}, {Sqrt[2]}}], {x, 1000000}]
```

The results are:

- Without `Echo`: 1.84s
- With `QuietEcho` wrapped around everything: 2.76s
- With the new definition: 2.42s
- With the old definition: 5.61s

---

### Old version

```
crit = 2;
SetAttributes[MyEcho, HoldAll]
Module[{res},MyEcho[label_, return_, subexpr___] :=
  If[NumberQ[label],If[label >= crit, return,
    label++; res = Echo[return, subexpr];
    If[label == crit, Print["Already " <> ToString[crit] <> " Echo here!\nNo more Echo allowed!!!!"]];res],
  label = 1; Echo[return, subexpr]]]

$Pre = 
   Function[{expr}, ReleaseHold[Hold[expr] /. HoldPattern[Echo[subexpr__]] :> 
       With[{u = Unique[]}, MyEcho[u, subexpr] /; True]], HoldAll]
```

Similar results, but a bit more integrated and more carefully protected.

[image: IMG]

Note that one can still save the old `$Pre` by adding it in front of this code.(one must limit the functionality of old `$Pre` to an extent that full evaluation of expressions is forbidden)

Answer (score 10):

Here is how I would approach this:

```
Clear[myEcho, myEchoCounter]
myEcho::stop = "Further output from `` will be suppressed during evaluation of In[``].";
myEcho[, ] := myEcho[];
myEcho[label_: Null, max_: 3][expr_] /; myEchoCounter[$Line, label] >= max := expr
myEcho[label_: Null, max_: 3][expr_] := (
   If[Not@NumberQ[myEchoCounter[$Line, label]], myEchoCounter[$Line, label] = 0];
   If[myEchoCounter[$Line, label] < max, 
    If[MatchQ[label, Null | None], Echo[expr], Echo[expr, label]]];
   If[++myEchoCounter[$Line, label] == max, 
    Message[myEcho::stop, "myEcho"[label, max], $Line]];
   expr);
```

Now

```
(myEcho["Before Table"][x]; Table[myEcho["Table"][x], {x, 10}]; myEcho["After Table"][x])

(Table[myEcho[, 3][x], {x, 10}]; Table[myEcho[, 6][x], {x, 10}])
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This is solution near to perfect,I will accept it after 36h if there is no better answer.

Comment: Just when we don't set any label or we set a same label,we cannot get the result [we want](https://ooo.0o0.ooo/2017/03/23/58d3c4c33263f.jpg),I don't sure whether `$ModuleNumber` can help or not.

Comment: @yode What you call "unexpected" is actually "by design": **on the same `$Line`** `myEcho` with the same label (or without a label) prints no more than `max` (by default 3) times.

Comment: So I just wonder we can add a `$ModuleNumber` after our label but we don't show that `$**`

Comment: Adding this code will automate the labelling process for `Echo`. `$Pre =.; $Pre = 
 Function[u, 
  Module[{c = 0}, (Hold[u]) /. 
      HoldPattern[Echo[a__]] :> 
       RuleCondition[Inactive[myEcho][++c][a]]] // Activate // 
   ReleaseHold, HoldAll];`

Comment: @yode As Kuba correctly say, you should decide for yourself at what moment of evaluation `myEcho` should be suppressed. From your comments it looks like you wish to have the counter to be reset for every `Table` on the same `$Line`. It is possible but difficult to achieve (AFAICS it requires analysis of `Stack[]`), and at the same time with this approach you won't know from where the `myEcho` was printed (because they'll have identical labels). My approach is to assign different label to every `myEcho` and bind the counter to the label and `$Line`.

Comment: @yode Actually with my current implementation what you [showed](https://ooo.0o0.ooo/2017/03/23/58d3c4c33263f.jpg) is possible, try `Table[myEcho[, 3][x], {x, 10}]; Table[myEcho[, 6][x], {x, 10}]`.

Comment: Thanks for so many labors for it.And it's seem it is the best solution still.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do this:

```
In[1]:= << GeneralUtilities`

In[2]:= $MaximumEchoRate = 5;

In[3]:= Table[EchoHold@x, {x, 10}]

x \[Function] 1

x \[Function] 2

x \[Function] 3

x \[Function] 4

x \[Function] 5

During evaluation of In[3]:= Maximum echo rate exceeded, change $MaximumEchoRate to adjust.

Out[3]= {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

Comment: This is nice (+1), but it is a *rate*, and therefore time-dependent. It will echo no more than five times per second.

Comment: Good dig,bug I find it will ignore the second `Echo` in [this case](https://ooo.0o0.ooo/2017/03/24/58d4549d784e6.jpg).

Comment: And ``ImageApply[GeneralUtilities`EchoHold[#] &, ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]]``don't work normally

Answer (score -1):

I think this is probably slower than Kuba's solution in comments, but does

```
myEcho[x_,n_:5]:=If[x<=n,Echo[x],Identity[x]];

Table[myEcho@x,{x,10}]
```

not achieve what you're looking for?

Comment: Oh,we can judge the `x<=n` in the general case when we debug.such as `Table[myEcho[x^2, 3], {x, 10}]` just give one result,but it is sure a good think..

Comment: This is not what OP wants. `n` should be the number of times `Echo` prints, not the upper limit of the number  `Echo` prints.

Comment: Ah, sorry, misunderstood what you wanted.  How about `myEcho[fx_, x_, n_: 5] := If[x <= n, Echo[fx], Identity[fx]]`, with usage `Table[(x^2)~myEcho~x, {x, 10}]`?

Comment: @AnotherShruggingPhysicist What about `Table[(x^2)~myEcho~x, {x, 10, 20}]`? You cannot assume `Table` or a iterator like `x` exists. Even you can, you are also assuming the iterator starting with 1. If you insist on similar approach and remove this `x` parameter, the best you can achieve is probably the code in the last section of the question.