# Temporary Printing without pausing

Tags: monitoring

We have a long `Do` loop for our program in which we have put a counter to see the stage of process.

```
counter=0;Do[

  a program; counter+=counter;
  Print[counter]
  ,{i,1,10^6}];
```

But we do not want to have a cell devoted to each counter when it is printed. If this happens, we will have `10^6` cells below each other which consume a huge space in a notebook of *Mathematica*. Actually we wish to have a temporary printing process. Of course, the running program takes a long time to be done and we do not need `Pause[nSeconds]` that is emphasized in the *Mathematica* documents. We just want to see temporarily the counter once the program finished in every iteration! We have seen [this link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6472/intermediate-display-similar-to-printtemporary) and [this link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35139/monitoring-progress-of-long-calculations) but they do not work for us efficiently.

Comment: Check `Monitor`, or skip `Print` and create `Dynamic @ counter` before running the loop.

Comment: Do you mean: `Monitor[Dynamic@j, Do[j = i + 1, {i, 1, 40}]]`?

Comment: It just print 41!!!

Comment: "or" meant "or", not "and".

Comment: We want to see temporarily  2   3  .......41

Comment: See also: [How to create a progress bar](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5978/5478)

Comment: Did you look up Monitor in the documentation?  It is all explained there.  *Don't guess at the syntax, look it up!!*

Comment: I don't understand that question.

Comment: So sorry I could understand what you said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the Documentation page for [`Monitor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Monitor.html). Here is a quick example:

```
program := Pause[.2]
Monitor[Do[program, {i, 1, 40}], i]
```

---

> Of course, the running program takes a long time to be done and we do not need `Pause[nSeconds]` that is emphasized in the *Mathematica* documents.

`Pause[nSeconds]` is just a stub for a program that takes significant time to compute, nothing more. Replace it with a call to your actual program!

---

Related:

- [How to make a custom Echo](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140818/280)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a file to decide if you want the program to print variables or not. For instance, only if the file exists, the program print variables which you are interested in.

It's tested on macOS, it should work on Linux as well.

1. Evaluate the cell
2. Execute the shell command whenever you want to check the status.

In:

Mathematica

```
ClearAll[debug]
debugQ[] := FileExistsQ["debug.txt"]
debugQ[]
Do[(Which[debugQ[], Print@i]; i), {i, 1, 10^8}]
```

Shell

```
echo 1 > debug.txt;rm debug.txt
```

Out:

[image]

Comment: Please explain what does the shell command `echo 1 > debug.txt;rm debug.txt` do exactly? Is it for Windows or for Linux?

Comment: It might work on windows if you can use Bash on Windows. the shell command creates debug.txt and then delete it. During the short period of time, the program will print debug messages when the program detects that debug.txt exists.

Comment: @UnchartedWorks Thanks, I assumed that it should be so but when run using `cmd` on Windows this command just creates the file "debug.txt" with contents "1 ;rm debug.txt".

Comment: If the program takes long time to evaluate, it simply may not notice the quick creation-deletion procedure, which consequently won't have any effect.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov dir > debug.txt & del debug.txt

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Not really, Front end won' t evaluate any new expression before the current expression is evaluated.

Comment: Yes, but it isn't related to `debugQ[]` which is evaluated in the Kernel.

Comment: @ AlexeyPopkov It depends on how often the program checks the file. If the interval of checking the file is long, you can just create the file and don't delete it immediately.

Comment: That's what I talked about: this approach is only reliable when `debugQ[]` is evaluated *very often*.

Comment: It's possible to use a new front end to send a new expression to the same kernel, however the setup is complicated. I think it's unnecessary in this case.

Comment: I would rather say it's on demand. It's like interrupt but not polling.

Comment: The idea of your answer is interesting but IMHO has narrow applicability. In general it is simpler to create a Palette with a button which will turn on printing of (for example) 10 debug messages.